# How to create pop up dialog in android

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, passwords

I am brand new to android studio and I have only managed to replace images in the app.

I have been given ta task at work to edit an existing app (IAXRPT) and change it so we could use it as a company. I have currently only changed icons and the logo of the app so it is branded to our company.

I am now looking to implement a password pop up box on certain tabs of the app. However, I have no idea in where to start.

I have tried researching into it but the tutorials I have been looking at all require tapping a box in order for the pop-up to appear. I was it to be automatic, in order to stop the user from changing any settings on the certain tabs without a password.

I don't want to get rid of the tabs all together as if we need to change any settings on them, then we can (with a password).

Thanks a lot guys and girls, and I hope to hear back from you all very soon.

-Liam.

Comment: you want the pop up to automatically come? is that want you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But I would like there to be some sort of verification there so only people with a password can get past the pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

You could either create a custom implementation of a dialog by creating a class which extends DialogFragment.

Or, you could use the android Alert Dialog with a EdiText field to ask the user for a password, and override the action buttons for your specific implementation.

Either way, here are some good sources:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Hi there, I did have a read through one of those sources earlier! I found that the "Creating a custom layout" was very similar to what I wanted. However this looks as if it is creating another page in order to login? Where as I would like a pop-up with a text field that only closes if a certain string of text is entered into it. And if not, then it stays "popped-up". Then if cancel is pressed, then it reverts it back to the previous page. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a `ViewPager` that shows pages using a `PageAdapter`.

In which case you can do the following:

```
myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
        askForPassword();
    }
});

private void askForPassword() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter Password:");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);  
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        // you need to implement a check that the password is ok
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment. I dont think that I have a ViewPager. The app has a tab with 4 pages to choose from. I think I just need some code to add into each ".xml" file that I want the dialog to pop-up in. Would the code you provided still work? Thanks.

Comment: how are you implementing the `4 pages to choose from` part? usually in Android you'd use a TabLayout for the tabs part, and a ViewPager for the pages part, if you're using a different way, please explain it

Comment: I believe that it is a tab layout for the tab part. And a linear layout for the displaying of the page?? Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, the TabLayout needs to know where to move the current screen. you can change the `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` in my answer to `TabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener` but if the user can also swipe left/right to switch screens, you won't get your dialog in this scenario.

Comment: It isn't possible to swipe left/right to switch screens so I will try this code which you have given me and let you know if it works! Do I need to add a password that is correct in the code, in order for it to verify if it is correct or not when I input it when the app is running? Thanks.

Comment: i don't know, that's up to your implementation of what a correct-password is.

Comment: I have added the code into several .xml files in the app and each tab that I open just opens as usual. It's as if it is totally ignoring the code I have inserted? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how you are adding Java code into xml files, you'd have to post your tabs/screens code into your questions